# Fast pdf to jpg conversion on Linux wanted

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am currently using ImageMagick to convert PDFs to JPEG raster images. 
It is painfully slow and uses up a lot of memory.

The command I used was:

```
convert -geometry 1024x768 -density 200 -colorspace RGB foo.pdf bar%02d.jpg
```

I guess that it's slow because it uses Ghostscript. 
**But there must be a faster way to do that on a Linux box.**

Has anybody found a better solution?

Comment: How much time, how much memory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using Ghostscript directly (instead of using ImageMagick's `convert` command, which calls Ghostscript indirectly) is indeed faster. And it gives you more control about conversion parameters. Try

```
gs \
   -sDEVICE=jpeg   \
   -o bar_%03d.jpg \
   -dJPEGQ=95      \
   -r600x600       \
   -g4960x7016     \
   foo.pdf
```

where

- `-o`: determines output path+filename (and saves usage of `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE`)
- `-dJPEGQ`: sets JPEG quality to 95%
- `-r`: sets resolution to 600dpi
- `-g`: sets image size to 4960x7016px
- `-sDEVICE`: sets output as JPEG

This command will probably be still to slow for you and create files bigger than expected. For smaller filesizes and faster execution try this (which probably comes close to output quality of your `convert` commandline):

```
gs \
   -sDEVICE=jpeg   \
   -o bar_%03d_200dpi_q80.jpg \
   -dJPEGQ=80      \
   -r200x200       \
   -g1653x2339     \
   foo.pdf
```

or even

```
gs \
   -sDEVICE=jpeg   \
   -o bar_%03d_default_a4.jpg \
   -sPAPERSIZE=a4 \
   foo.pdf
```

(which gives 72dpi resolution, often good enough for most screens and for most web applications).

Comment: You're right. I really didn't thing that Imagemagick would be the bottleneck. But I probably should have tried. Thanks also for the great examples!

Comment: Thanks! Saved my day!

Answer (score 10):

BTW, one of the reasons ImageMagick is so much slower is that it calls Ghostscript twice. It does not convert PDF => PNG in one go, but uses 2 different steps:

- it first uses Ghostscript for `PDF => PostScript` conversion;
- it then uses Ghostscript for `PostScript => PNG` conversion.

You can learn about the detailed settings ImageMagick's "delegates" (the external programs ImageMagick uses, such as Ghostscript) by typing

```
convert -list delegate
```

(On my system that's a list of 32 different commands.) Now to see which commands are used to convert to PNG, use this:

```
convert -list delegate | grep -i png
```

Ok, this was for Linux. If you are on Windows, try this:

```
convert -list delegate | findstr /i png
```

You'll discover that IM does produce PNG only from PS or EPS input. So how does IM get (E)PS from your PDF? Easy:

```
convert -list delegate | findstr /i PDF
convert -list delegate | grep -i PDF
```

Ah! It uses Ghostscript to make a PDF => PS conversion, then uses Ghostscript again to make a PS => PNG conversion. Works, but isn't the most efficient way **if you know that Ghostscript can do PDF => PNG in *one* go. And faster. And in much better quality.**

About IM's handling of PDF conversion to images via the Ghostscript delegate you should know two things first and foremost:

1. By default, if you don't give an extra parameter, Ghostscript will output images with a 72dpi resolution. That's why sometimes people here suggest to add `-density 600` as a `convert` parameter which tells Ghostscript to use a 600 dpi resolution for its image output.
2. The detour of IM to call Ghostscript twice to convert first `PDF => PS` and then `PS => PNG` is a real blunder. Because you ***never*** win and harldy keep quality in the first step, but very often loose some. Reasons:

   - PDF can handle transparencies, which PostScript can not.
   - PDF can embed TrueType fonts, which PostScript can not. etc.pp.
     (Conversion in the opposite direction, `PS => PDF`, therefor is not that critical....)

That's why I'd suggested you convert your PDFs in one go to PNG (or JPEG) using Ghostscript directly. And use the [most recent version 8.71](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/) (soon to be released: 9.00) of Ghostscript...

Answer (score 6):

The program `pdftoppm` from the poppler package is also able to create JPEGs, and for
me it is about twice as fast as using `gs` as described above:

```
pdftoppm -jpeg -r 300 foo.pdf foo.jpg
```

Comment: What a great suggestion. Just fixed a major, app-crashing bug my switching to pdftoppm thanks to this answer -- never knew about it before!

Comment: You, sir, deserve a medal for this :)

Comment: it is not faster than gs

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, [MuPDF](http://mupdf.com/) is a lot faster than Ghostscript. It is a much newer project without much of the cruft in gs.
Try if it fits for your usecase!

`mudraw -w 1024 -h 768 -r 200 -c rgb -o bar%d.png foo.pdf`

If you have a older linux distribution and installed mupdf-tools from the repository, `mudraw` might still be called `pdfdraw`

You then have to convert the png to jpeg using for example imagemagick. But it will still be faster than Ghostscript.

Comment: In my test MuPDF's PDF to PNG convertion is about 5-6 times faster than Ghostscript. Thank you for solution!

Comment: This is incredibly useful. It takes seconds where Ghostscript would take minutes, plus the command line is a breeze! Thank you very much for bringing this to my attention!